# How to execute pgAgent in Postgressql

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, pgagent

My setting is as below. but my agent never works. And I don't know where the log is exported.

this is no error even when I run it directly.

By the way my I'm using pgAdmin4 Version 4.21. and pgAgent version is 4.0.0.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]